# Deleting 'Old' Restore Purchase Transactions

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have been trying to test the Restore Purchases function in a project, but I'm faced with a continual feed of this error:

> Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because
>   already restoring transactions

I deleted a sandbox tester account, I presume one that has a restore purchase still caught in the payments loop. I realise I should NEVER delete a sandbox test account, but it's a little late for that.

Is there anything I can do to flush out the Restore Transactions caught in this never ending loop?

EDIT:

My amended code:

Pre-amble:

```
class InAppPurchaseViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var product_id: NSString?;

@IBOutlet weak var unlockAction: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {   
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)   
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
... }
```

1. The Purchase:

   @IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {

   ```
   product_id = "xxxx.iap.removeads";


   //Check if product is purchased
   if (defaults.boolForKey("purchased")){
       print("User already purchased this")
       // Hide a view or show content depends on your requirement
   }

   else if (!defaults.boolForKey("Purchased")){
       print("User has not yet purchased this")
   }


   print("About to fetch the products");

   // We check that user can make payments.
   if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
   {
       let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
       let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
       productsRequest.delegate = self;
       productsRequest.start();
       print("User can make purchases and will fetch products from Apple Store now");
   }else{
       print("User can't make purchases");
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   // Proceed to buy the product.
   func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
   print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
   let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
   SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

   }

   func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

   let count : Int = response.products.count
   if (count>0) {

       let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
       if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
           print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
           print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
           print(validProduct.price)
           buyProduct(validProduct);
       } else {
           print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
       }
   } else {
       print("nothing")
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   func request(request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
   print("Error Fetching product information");
   }


   func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])   {
   print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

   for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
       if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
           switch trans.transactionState {

           case .Purchased:
               print("Product Purchased")

               let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You.", message: "Thank you for your purchase!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
               alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
               self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
               SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
               defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
               break;

           case .Failed:
               print("Purchased Failed");
               SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
               break;

           case .Restored:
               print("Already Purchased");
               SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
               break;

           default:
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. The Restore:

   ```
   @IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: AnyObject) {
   product_id = "xxxx.iap.removeads";
   SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()

   func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

       for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
           if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
               switch trans.transactionState {
               case .Restored:
                   SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                   let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                   alert.show()
                   break;

               case .Failed:
                   SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                   let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Sorry", message: "Your purchase(s) could not be restored.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                   alert.show()
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new test user, make the purchase, then test for a restore.  Apple makes it really difficult for making test users for in-app purchases.  In my experience I always create new test users, because you cannot delete any of their old purchases.  So if you want to test an initial purchase twice, you will need two test users.

But as for your problem, you should only be checking for transactions once in this method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState){
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
```

And make sure you have this too:

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %lu", (unsigned long)queue.transactions.count);
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions){
    if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
        //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
        NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

        //if you have more than one in-app purchase product,
        //you restore the correct product for the identifier.
        //For example, you could use
        //if(productID == kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier)
        //to get the product identifier for the
        //restored purchases, you can use
        //
        //NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        break;
    }
}
}
```

And you should be calling restore purchases like this:

```
- (IBAction) restore {
//this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I think I have over-thought this and just ended up confusing myself. I have added the `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` into the `viewDidLoad` section as per suggestion in a related question by @crashoverride777, and amended my code to what I think may work. I don't quite follow your instructions exactly ... apologies. Will my above amended code work?

Comment: I'm not unlocking any features or levels in my app for users that buy the non-consumable, simply loading a check in the `viewDidLoad` section of my index page/landing page that determines whether a user has purchased the app or not, and then showing them adverts or otherwise (if they've purchased ad-free browsing).

Comment: @KatherineJenkins I think the amended code you posted will work. I'm not much of a swift developer, so I can't tell exactly what is going on but it looks like you have all the right delegate functions included

Comment: Hallelujah! I'm literally off to the pub now to down a gallon of beer! lol ... Will test it when I get to the office tomorrow :-)